# Tensorflow Serving on docker using tflite file

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I was trying to deploy ML model with the Tensorflow Serving. Even though I added sharing file path on the docker. This error keep comes out somehow. And I am working with a tflite file to deploy it, and it seems like not work at all. Please help and give some recommendations or feedback.

[file sharing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj3Ef.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please prefer code than image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `TF Saved Model Format` (.pb).

save your model as save model format:

```
model.save('saved_model/1/', save_format="tf")
```

[This Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/tfx_for_mobile) shows how you can change your .tflite model to a standard model. It might be helpful.

Also in your picture: your mount directory is incorrect in tensorflow docker serving. you can use this command to run docker:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/my_model/,target=/models/my_model \
  -e MODEL_NAME=my_model -t tensorflow/serving
```

Comment: this is a wrong answer, you can do it, check out the docs here https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/8c1162bf663d415852f0408277653d4295e05b42/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc#L245

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is wrong. You actually can serve TFLite model w/ TF Serving. It is a hidden feature that not many ppl know. It's documented in: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/8c1162bf663d415852f0408277653d4295e05b42/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc#L245

'--prefer_tflite_model=true' is the flag to enable it. Here is an example:

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
   -v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" \
   -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two \
   tensorflow/serving \   
   --prefer_tflite_model=true
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to serve a full model (.pb format) alongside a tflite model in the same tf-serving? I know it's possible to serve multiple models, but does this flag you've mentioned mean that they _all_ have to be tflite?

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest that the tflite model should be in a certain directory with a certain name. Is that correct?